# How do I get hardware information(exact Computer model, version) without any external tool in Linux or Ubuntu? Or How do lshw gets this info below?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I do not want to use any tool like lshw , inex , hardinfo, hwinfo .They show exact model , product , version etc for my ubuntu . But how ? How can I get these info:

- product: HP Notebook (M9V70PA#ACJ);
- vendor: Hewlett-Packard ;
- version: Type1ProductConfigId

Comment: You say you don't want to use an existing tool? why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I don't want to reinvent, I just want to understand/learn how/where do they get it. Does ubuntu store all this? where ?

Comment: Then why not just look at the code for the tools you mentioned before asking?

Comment: trying from last 2 days to understand lshw code, really not getting anything.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those tools and similar like dmidecode all read a section of memory called the DMI tables mapped in from the BIOS which holds the information.

The DMI spec can be found here: http://www.dmtf.org/standards/dmi

Comment: Thanks, how can I get this information/tables in ubuntu?